# How to use firestore query to perform a user role based login for javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a login using javascript and firestore as the backend functions. It seems that my code does not perform the query and the user id given by firebase is not being pulled out from the cloud. what my current code does is just redirect any user to patientDashboard.php regardless of their 'occupation'

Here is my code

```
(function(){//initialize the firebase app
    var config = {

        }; 

        firebase.initializeApp(config);
        var auth = null;
        var loginBtn= document.getElementById('btnLogin');
        // var user = db.collection("users");
        // var db = firebase.firestore();
        firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION;

    //Login
    loginBtn.addEventListener('click', async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if( $('#email').val() != '' && $('#password').val() != '' ){
        //login the user
        var data = {
            email: $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
        };
        try{
            const userCredential = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password);
            let uid = userCredential.user.uid;
            var documents = await firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid);
            documents.get().then(function(doc){
                if(doc.data['occupation'] != 'Doctor'){
                    window.location.href = "patientDashboard.php"; 
                }
                else {
                    window.location.href = "doctorDashboard.php";  
                }                  
            });
        }    
        catch(err){
            console.log("Login Failed!", err);
            window.alert("Login Failed!", err);
        }
    }
});
})();
```

what I want to accomplish is a proper login backend function based on the user's occupation. But at the moment it only redirects to the aforementioned page. I suspect the culprit is the query code that I made..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do `doc.data['occupation']`.

You need to either use the [`data()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot?authuser=0#data) **method** as follows:

```
if(doc.data().occupation != 'Doctor') {...}
```

or use the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot?authuser=0#get) method as follows:

```
if(doc.get('occupation') != 'Doctor') {...}
```

---

### EDIT:

In addition, there is another error in your code. You are mixing up the use of `async/await` and of the `then()` method. You should adapt your code as follows

```
    var document = await firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).get();

    //document is a DocumentSnapshot, we can call the get() method

    if (document.get('occupation') != 'Doctor'){
       window.location.href = "patientDashboard.php"; 
    }
    else {
       window.location.href = "doctorDashboard.php";  
    }
```

---

Be aware that with this code you are NOT implementing a genuine role-based access control system. You are just redirecting the user based on a value in its `user` document. Someone could easily reverse engineer your app and redirects to the wrong page.

If you want to set up a role-based access control system, you may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which shows how to do with Custom Claims. (*disclaimer, I'm the author*)

Comment: I already tried your suggestion but what happens the program still signs in the user to the patientDashboard.php regardless of the occupation. `documents.get().then(function(doc){...})` I feel like the error is coming here...

Comment: " the program still signs in the user to the patientDashboard.php" What do you exactly mean? Does it **redirect** to `patientDashboard.php`??

Comment: basically Im trying to sign in a doctor account but it still signs it as a patient and it redirects to patientDashboard.php

Comment: Actually note if the call to `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` is successful the user **is signed in** as a Firebase user. This is independent of the value of occupation. But  ow I see another error in your code. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @setted Note that I had forgotten to add `get()` at the end of the first line of the EDIT!

Comment: Never mind I added `get()` in the query, I also saw your recent comment, thank you for your assistance! @Renaud Tarnec